Swithching a control ON/ OFF with a single push button and using the same push button as controller Input
I have attached a reference schematics. The idea is to push the button (SW1) to turn the controller ON (via VCC I suppose), and when it is ON, the button can be used as Input to the controller. If the controller detects that the button has been pressed for a certain duration, it sends a signal to turn the device back off.
This is what I suppose the reference circuit does. But how does it do this? I need help understanding.
Thanks!


the function is not done by the circuit ... it is performed by the connected device, probably a microcontroller

@jsotola lets say I want to do it with a controller, then how to do it? Single press turns the controller ON, then when the button is pressed for longer duration, it turns the circuit OFF. By the way can you understand, how will this circuit even work (assuming we have MCU attached)

where did you get the circuit? ... please add a reference to the circuit into your question ... at first glance Q6 appears to be backward

@jsotola sorry don't have the reference. It was shared with me, and they said it can do what is required. That is why I am having trouble understanding this (if this circuit is even useful or not).

@jsotola: Q6 is fine, it's just functioning as reverse-battery protection only. It's Q1 that's doing the actual power switching.

The operation is fairly straightforward. Q6 is just functioning as reverse-battery protection only.
When the circuit is off (Enable is low), the activation of S1 pulls the gate of Q1 low, turning it on. While S1 is still being held, the software starts up and drives Enable high, which causes Q2 to also pull Q1's gate low. This should only take a few milliseconds at most, after which S1 can be released.
Now the circuit is on. The state of S1 can be read by the software via the On/Off connection to D10. (Note that there needs to be a pull-up on this signal, either inside or outside the MCU, and the diodes need to be reversed as Jasen Слава Україні pointed out.) This button can be used for anything at this point, but a common thing would be that if it is held for several seconds, the software will initiate a power-down sequence.
The power-down sequence consists of doing whatever functional shut-down of the application code is required (including turning off anything that emits light in the user interface), then driving Enable low, and then doing nothing else (i.e., executing a "halt" or "loop-to-self" instruction) until the power goes off. If the user is still holding the button, Vcc will stay high until they release it, but in any case, nothing else will happen until the power actually goes away.

Thank you so much. I will try it out as well. The Q6 that's just for reverse polarity protection right?

Yes, see edits above.

D10 is obviously wrong, it should probably be BAT54C (diodes the other way round)
The circuit works like this: Q6 is reverse polarity protection,
Q1 turns the supply to VCC on or off,
Q2 takes the signal from the controller and turns VCC on (by making the gate of Q1 low) when it receives a high signal at it base.  S1 (Via updated D10) does the same thing when pressed.
The controller (via the other end of D10 and a pull-up) can monitor S1 to detect when it is pressed.

Thank you so much! I will make a prototype circuit and test it out.
